# Paypal Sandbox returning INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm getting the dreaded INTERNAL_ERROR from PayPal today. This code was actually working yesterday, but I had to create a new facilitator account so I could add more funds.

Here is the response from PayPay:

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => INTERNAL_ERROR
    [message] => An internal service error has occurred.
    [debug_id] => 75ad8f53ee782
    [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors
)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sanddox having issues and still has an open issue with sandbox. It is intermittent though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.paypal-notify.com for status on production and sandbox servers. As of right now there is an alert for issues in the sandbox environment affecting the REST API.